# Вопрос по парсингу json в python

Tags: python, json

У меня есть несколько json файлов, которые надо объединить в один. Для этого мне нужно сначала достать данные с каждого файла в словари python. Я загрузил один json в объект питона и пытался его напечатать. Но файл оказался слишком большим, и терминал просто завис. Причем я даже не могу получить отдельные элементы, т.к. файл json записан в одну строку и там фиг что разберешь.

Вот код:

```
import json

with open('C:\Practise JSON\JSON\json1.json') as file:
    df = json.load(file)

dfjs = json.dumps(df, indent=2)
print(dfjs[str(3876921)])
```

Comment: Ситуация более-менее понятна, а в чём вопрос -- не очень. Можно ли поподробнее?

Comment: Если нужно получить значение по ключу "3876921", то нужно получать его из df, а не из dfjs: `print(df["3876921"])` (если там конечно вообще есть такой ключ). Если df - словарь, то dfjs - строка, в которую вы словарь превратили с помощью json.dumps.